Using @State but getting error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable
Please, can someone explain why I can add another eventArray if I define the instance (t2Array) in onAppear while, if I declare it as @State var t3Array at the beginning of the struct, I get the following error when I attempt to append a value:

Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

The struct for both is:
struct T2 {
    var name : String
    var eventArray : [String]
}

The following local variable works fine in onAppear:
var t2Array = [T2(name: "T2", eventArray: ["event1"])]
t2Array[0].eventArray.append("event2")

But when I attempt to update the property, t3Array, I get the error:
t3Array = [T2(name: "T2", eventArray: ["event1"])]
self.t3Array[0].eventArray.append("event2")       // error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

Here is the full code example:
struct T2 {
    var name : String
    var eventArray : [String]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var t3Array:[T2]?
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear(perform: {
             var t2Array = [T2(name: "T2", eventArray: ["event1"])]
             t2Array[0].eventArray.append("event2")
            
             t3Array = [T2(name: "T2", eventArray: ["event1"])]
             self.t3Array[0].eventArray.append("event2")        // error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable
        })
    }
}


Please show a [mre]

t3Array is optional, so you would need something like t3Array?[0].eventArray.append("event2"). Alternatively, don’t make it an optional, e.g., @State var t3Array: [T2] = [].

Thx, that was it, should have seen it on my own, but was somehow missleaded by the error message. Do you put it as the answer, then I can accept it

The error is misleading. The issue is that t3Array is an optional. So, you can either:

Use the optional like so:
t3Array?[0].eventArray.append("event2")


Or, alternatively, don’t make it an optional, e.g.,
@State var t3Array: [T2] = []



In SwiftUI, I would lean towards the second option, but both work.


So the error is not showing your actual mistake.
You're getting an error because you have not done Optional chaining in your code, in swift or swiftUI we cannot use a optional property directly in our code we have several ways to handle optionals like force unwrapping, optional chaining etc...In your code you can use optional chaining like:

self.t3Array?[0].eventArray.append("event2")


Or you can simply change the t3Array to non-optional like:

@State var t3Array:[T2]
